# In CImg, how to draw text on a specific slice of a 3D image?

Tags: cimg

Using CImg, I can draw a text string on a 2D image easily. For example, if you create a 2D image:

```
CImg<unsigned char> img(180, 160, 1, 3);
```

Then you can draw "Hello" on it using the draw_text function:

```
img.draw_text(5, 2, "Hello", white, 0, 1, 24);
```

But if I have a 3D image like this:

```
CImg<unsigned char> img(180, 160, 10, 3);
```

I want to draw the text string on the 2nd slice. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You should use CImg<>::get_slice() and CImg::draw() to extract the slice, draw text on it,then put the modified slice back in your volumetric image.

Comment: But how to put the modified slice back to the image? I didn't see an apparent method in the CImg for doing this. Looks like get_slice() will return a 2D CImg object that does not share the memory with the original 3D CImg object. So changing the returned slice does not affect the original image. I know I can create a new 2D CImg object, draw on it, then use draw_image method to put the 2D image on the specific 3D slice, but this way does not need to use get_slice method. So I think there is a more direct way of doing this.